# Why is the tree command not included in Ubuntu server?

Tags: server

Is installing the tree command line utility on Ubuntu server has security issues?  It's not included by default on the server.

Comment: What's "tree"? Some googling doesn't turn up anything obvious...

Comment: Vote to close as not a real question.

Comment: It's a real question!
tree is a command line utility that shows the directory structure. It's INCLUDED in the desktop, but MISSING in the server.
Since I find it useful, I wanted to install it on the server as well, but wasn't sure if it's secure or why the Ubuntu team didn't include it on the server in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I will be describing now is most likely a very hypothetical situation.

1. Assume you are running *tree* on a part of the filesystem where any user can create files, such as under `/tmp` or `/var/tmp`.
2. Assume that a malicious user has created very explicitly special file names in that location. That could either have been done by having an actual user account on the system or by "tricking" a slightly vulnerable and publicly available server daemon.
3. Assume there is a actual vulnerability/weakness in *tree* regarding how it deals with "odd" file names.

Under such circumstances it is possible that *tree* could be tricked into running unintended instructions with the privileges on your user account. Obviously that damage would be far worse assuming *tree* had been called with root privileges.

Yet, this is nothing different from what you expose yourself to every time you use any application to handle data created by an external/unknown party. No matter if you viewing a web page in your browser, listening to a mp3 file in your music player or editing a document in your word processor you still need to trust your application to handle incoming data in a sane manner.

This is by the way why security vulnerabilities in a web browsers are such a big deal, since they are constantly exposed to input from external/unknown parties. The same, even more, goes for server daemons, where a potential attacker has a constant opportunity to feed you "bad" input data. Compare this to your calculator, where you yourself are the one inputing all the data as you feed it numbers.

**Summarize:**

Yes, there is a theoretical security consideration in installing and running *tree*, just like with pretty much any other software.

That being said, the majority of applications you find in the Ubuntu repositories will be reasonable safe to install and to use. As long as we are talking about regular user applications I don't think you should worry to much.

(Save your worries for publicly reachable server daemons.)

Answer (score 10):

I suspect tree is not installed by default because it is in `universe` (applications have to be in `main` before they can be installed as default).

A quick look through the [changelog](http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/changes.html) doesn't show a record of security issues, and there are no [bug reports in Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tree/+bugs), even going back as far as Dapper.

So my advice would be to just go ahead and install `tree` on your server, it's probably safer than a lot of popular server applications.